# Jenkins Groovy: What triggered job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class).each {it ->
println it.fullName
println it.getLastBuild().getTime()
}
```

I want to get list of jobs triggered automatically. Now i have list of all jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [Cause](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Cause.html) which triggered the build.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class).each {
  hudson.model.Cause cause = it.getLastBuild().getCause(hudson.model.Cause.class)
  println "Is triggered by user: " + (cause.class == hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
}
```

This class has many subclasses, which you can you to determine what triggered the build:

> Cause.LegacyCodeCause, Cause.RemoteCause, Cause.UpstreamCause,
>   Cause.UpstreamCause.DeeplyNestedUpstreamCause, Cause.UserCause,
>   Cause.UserIdCause, SCMTrigger.SCMTriggerCause,
>   TimerTrigger.TimerTriggerCause

Comment: How to check if job has schedule?

Comment: `TimerTrigger.TimerTriggerCause` ? Youn can get all triggers from the AbstractProject by `getTriggers()`

Answer (score 0):

```
println currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)