# List all timely triggered jobs on Jenkins in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I want to list all the jobs that are timely triggered in my jenkins.
I tried the below code for it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

void log(msg) {
    manager.listener.logger.println(msg)
}

hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItems().each  { job ->
  def cause = "${job.getPreviousBuild().getCauses()}"
  if (cause =~ "UserIdCause") {
        log("Triggered by user")
    }
  if (cause =~ "TimerTriggerCause") {
        log("Timely triggered Job name:"+ job.getName())
  }
}
```

It is giving me below error:

```
Groovy script failed:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getPreviousBuild() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
```

I dont know what is causing this error.
I have referred links:
[Jenkins library: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method xxx on null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642708/jenkins-library-java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-invoke-method-xxx-on-nul)

[Jenkins Groovy: What triggered job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651757/jenkins-groovy-what-triggered-job?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right after doing below modifications:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder

void log(msg) {
    manager.listener.logger.println(msg)
}

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class).each  { job ->
    if (job instanceof Folder) {
        log("[i] Folder found:" + job.getName())
    }
    else if(job.getLastBuild())
    {
        def cause = "${job.getLastBuild().getCauses()}"
        if (cause =~ "UserIdCause") {
            log("Job triggered by user: "+job.getName())
        }
        if (cause =~ "TimerTriggerCause") {
            log("Timely triggered Job: "+ job.getName())
        }
    }
}
```